# Edição inline não está funcionando

Tags: bug, status-pronto, edição

Normalmente quando clicamos em `Editar` abre a edição ali mesmo onde está a postagem e temos acesso à toda página facilitando imensamente porque dá contexto, dá acesso às ferramentas do site para pesquisar e você recebe notificações.

Desde ontem isso mudou e agora só é possível fazer a edição em página própria que complica bastante o que está sendo feito.

Atrapalha muito!

[image: Tela com edição separada]

Comment: Pelo jeito é geral: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346435/401803 | https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/396588

Comment: A solução temporária para isso é duplicar a guia e abrir a edição na outra. Eu clico com o botão do meio do mouse no título da pergunta, abro outra guia e vou editando.

Comment: Já foi arrumado: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/346488/401803 (testei aqui no SOpt e também foi)

Comment: @hkotsubo eu testei no meta e foi, cheguei até mudar a *tag*, mas no principal pra mim ainda tá caindo na página de edit, tentei várias vezes, durante 1 hora.

Comment: @Maniero Pra mim já aparece o inline tanto no meta quanto no principal

Comment: @hkotsubo Só porque eu falei agora foi.

Comment: Provavelmente foi [algum problema de cache](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/) :-)

Comment: Comigo está a funcionar bem(com antigamente)